# How to parse through the logsBloom of a block or transaction using solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, logs, bloom-filter

Currently trying to figure out how to parse through the `logsBloom` portion of block and transaction headers using solidity. I've researched the topic so far and have come to the understanding that RLP encoding will be required to transfer the data to the blockchain where it will be decoded by your contract, but have been unable to figure out the next steps.